# Use _trackPageview on pageload with jquery?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Okay, I've been looking far and wide for a simple example of this. I'm about to make a site public and it's kind of hard to test that your tracking-code works properly, so I just want to make sure this is right. Can I just add this to my header on the pages i want to add? The tracking code is already up and running.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxx-x");
pageTracker._trackPageview("/subdirectory/pagename"); </script>
```

If not, what should I do? I can't use the pagename-technique.

Comment: are you trying to add google analytic's tracking code?  i dont' quite understand the question.

Comment: Yes the trackingcode that is used for goals, I'll try to make it clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much what you need to do.

Comment: Another thing you need to do is include its script file (ga.js)